# Tutorials for BitcoinJ

Tags: bitcoinj

Beside the examples that come with BitcoinJ and the documentation on Google Code, does anyone know of any tutorials for using BitcoinJ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a 3 part article in JavaWorld about bitcoinj in 2011. It is obviously a bit dated but is a thorough introduction to it. First part:
http://javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2011/111122-bitcoin-for-beginners-part-1.html

Comment: Thanks Jim, I had seen this at one point but forgot about it. I've just reread it now, and for anyone else interested, it's definitely worth having a look.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the snippets in here helpful:  [Bitcoinj API](http://bitcoinaustria.github.io/devfest-bitcoinj/#/2/1).